# Размер кнопки на разных устройствах

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, button, ipad

Я заметил, что во многих разных приложениях кнопка для iPhone и iPad отличается размером. Кнопка на iPad больше.

Например:

iPhone 8 Plus:

[image]

iPad Pro 12,9:

[image]

Кнопка на iPad должна быть больше кнопки на iPhone или должна иметь одинаковый размер для всех устройств? Что говорит об этом Apple?

У меня есть кнопка в `storyboard`, и я создаю ограничения ширины и высоты:

[image]

Но моя кнопка имеет одинаковый размер для всех устройств. Например:

iPhone SE:

[image: iPhone SE]

iPad Pro 12,9: (На скрине кажется, что размер разный, но на самом деле это не так. При наложении размер одинаковый)

[image: iPad Pro 12,9]

**Update**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть Size Classes с помощью которых вы можете настроить констрейнты и они например будут отображатся только в landscape либо как в вашием примере: для iPhone и iPad
Выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а если посмотреть сам констрейнт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на последок [статейка](https://habr.com/post/235181/) с хабра (старовата немного правда, но подойдет)

---

апдейт

пример использования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я добавил два скриншота в вопрос. Вроде бы я использую все, что нужно. Но кнопка все равно остается 50x50 везде.

Comment: Вам нужно два констрейнта для размера добавить, потом в каждом добавить сайз класс как на втором скрине. На одном должно бить выбрано как на втором скрине( будет работать только для планшета) на втором наоборот

Comment: Добавил еще два скриншота. Что-то не так?

Comment: Размеры поменять нужно

Comment: На 1 скрине изменил в поле `constant `  размер с 50 на 100.  Но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: смотрите, думаю так будет понятнее

Comment: Да, так понятнее. Спасибо! Но у меня помимо этого есть еще вопрос. Вообще размер кнопок на iPad должен быть больше, чем на iPhone? Что Apple рекомендует по этому поводу? Пытался найти примеры у Apple..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/.  Вот

Comment: А если я получаю на iPad `conflicting constraints`. На работу это вроде не влияет, но как это исправить все же?

Comment: Значит у вас два констрейнта с разными размерами активны, посмотрите ui на брейкпоинте, там можно посмотреть все элементы которые на экране и их констрейнты

Comment: Пожалуйста ответьте. Смотрите, для моей кнопки в iPad я должен создать ограничение ширины и нажать «installed» wR hR. Для iPhone я должен создать еще одно ограничение ширины и нажать «installed» для wC hC, wR hC, wC hR? Это верно? Просто если я создаю для iPad «installed» wR hR, а для iPhone просто «installed», то когда я перехожу в iPad получаю conflicting constraints потому что у меня 2 ограничение ширины активны, а должно быть активно только одно?